# How to colorize hierarchically-ordered polygons?

Tags: cartography, algorithm, color, datastructure

I have to implement a solution for coloring a lot of polygons that are derived from a hierarchically-ordered dataset. The dataset can be compared to a family tree in terms of hierarchy. Most of the polygons that are on the same hierarchy level do not overlap with each other. This is not the case for parent polygons (as in a parent-child relationship), because they usually tend to portray the general combined area of the children. Therefore, parent polygons tend to overlap/intersect with the child polygons. The amount of children per parent node is not balanced and can range from 0, 20. The coloring should respect three different main aspects:

1. all colors of a hierarchical color scheme should be unique.
2. the colors should reflect the tree structure in terms of parent-child relationships
3. hierarchical depth should be encoded in color

I looked up different implementations of tree vertices coloring that come from InfoVis approaches. One of them would be: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6875961

Most of the papers that I read on this topic do not include the spatial component. The vertices coloring methods purely depend on the attribute relation rather than incorporating the spatial relation of the vertices. This might be problematic for cartography when these InfoVis ideas are directly applied to spatial data.

Since I could not find any relevant papers which translates these theorems from the InfoVis space into the Cartography space, I wanted to ask if anyone has either an idea on how to approach this problem or if anyone know about literature concerning this topic?